# How to make a database consult using a date and time variable?

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I have the following line code used to retrieve data from database:

```
DataTable newEquipmentTable = database.Connection.RetrieveData(database.AdapterType, string.Format("SELECT ID FROM Equipment WHERE Name = '{0}' AND CreatedOn = '{1}'", equipment.Name, equipment.CreatedOn.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")));
```

It returns an error saying "The conversion of varchar data type to a datetime datatype resulted in an out-of-range value"

When I make a direct consult, using the following query it returns the expected result.

```
SELECT ID FROM Equipment WHERE Name = 'aa' AND CreatedOn = '2012-04-17 19:42:49.650'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Be careful with SQL injection. What is the value of equipment.CreatedOn?

Comment: It's a value like '2012-04-17 19:42:49.650'

Comment: Can you not use a 'proper' parametrised query?

Comment: Are you sure that it is not DateTime.MinValue?

Comment: @Guilherme Campos: a value LIKE that one, but probably a value that is too large or too small for the exact datatype of CreatedOn (smalldatetime?).

Comment: Can you post the result of the string.Format? Would be good to know that it is creating the SQL statement that you expect.

Comment: @Dave, it doesn't matter whatever I could use, I just wanna know why it doesn't work and what's wrong.

Comment: @GoranObradovic, yes, I'm sure.

Comment: @GuilhermeCampos - With parameterised queries you don't need to use ToString(), etc, you use *native* data-types.  So, the framework deals with datatype conversions, and you won't experience this vague and hard to debug type of problem.  It also allows execution plan re-use, protects from sql injection attacks, allows simpler de-bugging and a whole host of other issues.  In short, you could spend time working out what is wrong in this one instance, and again every time something new comes up.  ***Or*** you could use a pre-existing, reliable, recommended, best-practice and secure alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that SQL's `datetime` type cannot hold values prior to `1753-01-01`.

Just inspect the SQL string with the debugger before it is used to query the database in order to find the problem.

However, the best thing to do is to use a parameterized query (like in [this example](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)); otherwise you're vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: That's the problem!!
My consult was returning a date before the permited on SQL.

Comment: I'm glad that solved it! Also, please try making a habit out of writing parameterized queries; building SQL statements by concatenating strings can lead to SQL injection vulnerabilities, which can get you in big trouble.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing a `String` value to select a `datetime` field. So you need to convert it to a datetime first:

```
Convert(datetime,'2012-04-17 19:42:49.650', 102)
```

Apart from that you might be open for [SQL-Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953.aspx) as @Mr47 has mentioned, use [`SqlParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx).

Comment: The RetrieveData requires a string query, so I need to pass a string as argument, not a datetime.

Comment: @GuilhermeCampos: That's why i've showed how to convert the string to datetime on dbms-side. You could pass `String.Format("Convert(datetime,{0},102)", equipment.CreatedOn.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"))` to `RetrieveData`.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of equipment.CreatedOn?

I think problem with the culture setting either in sql-server or your application. It cannot directly covert your date. User culture setting will solve problem.